# Проблема с простой формой ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, form

Суть проблемы в том, что меня настигла ошибка

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '[http://искомый_сайт.tmweb.ru/catalog/shuby/](http://%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.tmweb.ru/catalog/shuby/)'
>   (redirected from
>   '[http://искомый_сайт.ru/local/templates/newfurs/components/bitrix/catalog/catalog/bitrix/catalog.element/.default/send.php](http://%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru/local/templates/newfurs/components/bitrix/catalog/catalog/bitrix/catalog.element/.default/send.php)')
>   from origin '[http://искомый_сайт.ru](http://%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru)' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Объясняю, задача стоит в то, что бы запихнуть на страницу сайта (на битрикс) самую простую форму для захвата имени и телефона.
Реализовал самую простую форму на ajax. Но с такой ошибкой столкнулся впервые, прошу помощи, спасибо. Ниже форма, js и php.

ФОРМА

```
<form id="razmer">
   <select name="rarmer_v" title="Указать размер">
      <option value="40" name="rv40">40</option>
      <option value="42" name="rv42">42</option>
      <option value="44" name="rv44">44</option>
      <option value="46" name="rv46">46</option>
      <option value="48" name="rv48">48</option>
      <option value="50" name="rv50">50</option>
      <option value="52" name="rv52">52</option>
      <option value="54" name="rv54">54</option>
      <option value="56" name="rv56">56</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" /><br>
   <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон">              
   <button>Узнать</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#razmer").submit(function(){
         $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/local/templates/newfurs/components/bitrix/catalog/catalog/bitrix/catalog.element/.default/send.php",
              data: $(this).serialize()
         }).done(function(){
         alert("Спасибо!");
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

PHP

```
<?php 

$rec = "почта_реципиента@mail.ru";
$title = "Новая заявка с сайта искомый_сайт";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$rarmer_v = trim($_POST["rarmer_v"]);

$message = "Имя: $name \n Телефон: $phone \n Размер: $razmer_v";

mail($rec, $title, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $rec");

?>
```

Comment: Почитайте https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

Если не можете исключить редирект на сторонний сайт посмотрите в сторону jsonp. Попробуйте добавить в ваш код:

```
type: "POST",
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

Comment: Нет, не хочет, та же ошибка

Comment: Посмотри здесь https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/ , некоторое время назад решал подобную проблему, но как точно не помню, да и политика CORPS могла меняться в том числе в разных браузерах и их версиях.